# Add-on domain works in Wordpress but links still lead to subdomain

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this looks like a common question, and I assure you I've tried a bunch of responses, but none seem to work in my case. I'm a Wordpress noob so I might be making some basic error which I can't spot.

I will link you to the actual pages in question so you can see what's going on easily.

The main domain is: [visit-ceed.net](http://visit-ceed.net)

We created an add-on domain called [reprezentacija.me](http://reprezentacija.me) which can be accessed as a subdomain of the main domain here: http://visit-ceed.net/reprezentacije/.

Opening `reprezentacija.me` works fine, but all the links still point to the subdomain. How do I get the links to point to the add-on domain? So, instead of pointing to `http://visit-ceed.net/reprezentacije/category/novosti/fudbal/` the corresponding link should go to `http://reprezentacija.me/category/novosti/fudbal/`. Here is the htaccess file in the `reprezentacije/` directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I believe this is not an Htaccess problem, did you changed your blogurl and home url in the options at the admin panel (general) ? also, usually when doing a redirect (if that is what you mean by Add-on domain? ) you usually have an option to leave the original URL or use the new one on all pages (depending on your host )

Comment: Obmerk Kronen is correct. Apache's mod_rewrite module cannot alter the links on your pages, it can only redirect the request once the user clicks or types a URL. If you need to change the way links appear on a page then you need to edit the page.

Comment: Dump your entire wordpress database into a .sql file - open it up and do a search and replace over the entire document changing the old url to the new url.

Update database with new data.